# How can my django form grab current username and email and submit them into another database table?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

In my django project I have a form `VisitorRegForm` which collects `scanned_id` and `body_temp` and submits data to my database table `ClinicalData`, since the current user is already logged in, how can I make this form to also be able grab current logged in user's `username` and `email` (Note: `username` and `email` were both created **from the built-in django User model**) and submit these four items: `'scanned_id', 'body_temp', 'username', 'email'` into the database table `ClinicalData`?

Don't mind the missing details and inports, the form works and am able to submit `'scanned_id', 'body_temp'`. Help me on the easiest way I will be able to submit these four items: `'scanned_id', 'body_temp', 'username', 'email'` looking at the details shown in the files below:
Where should it be easier to achieve this; in the views.py or the template file?

**forms.py**

```
class VisitorRegForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class ScannerForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = ClinicalData
      fields = ['scanned_id', 'body_temp']
```

**models.py**

```
class ClinicalData(models.Model):
    ...
    scanned_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="Scanned ID", max_length=50, null=True)
    body_temp = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Body Temperature", max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name="Facility Name", max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Visitor Email", max_length=200, null=True)
    ...
```

**views.py**

Am assuming I might need like two variables here in the views that should help me like the ones i've commented out, if it should start from here, help me how it should succeed:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def scanEnter(request):

    #grab_username = function_to_grab_current_logged_in_username_HELP_ME_HERE
    #grab_email = function_to_grab_current_logged_in_user_email_HELP_ME_HERE

    form = ScannerForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScannerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('scanenter')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'scan_enter_fac.html', context)
```

**scan_enter_fac.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="">scanned_id<input type="text" id="multiple" class="form-control" placeholder="or Type ID here; e.g: ACCTS-147" name="scanned_id"></div>
    <div class="">body_temp<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g: 36.5" name="body_temp"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def scanEnter(request):

    #grab_username = function_to_grab_current_logged_in_username_HELP_ME_HERE
    #grab_email = function_to_grab_current_logged_in_user_email_HELP_ME_HERE

    form = ScannerForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScannerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.username = request.user.username #new
            form.email = request.user.email #new
            form.save()
            
            return redirect('scanenter')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'scan_enter_fac.html', context)
```

scan_enter_fac.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="">{{ form.scanned_id }}</div>
    <div class="">{{ form.body_temp }}</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @amadou sow Thanks for your quick reply, just here: form = forme.save(commit=False) I guess it should be like this form = forme.save(commit=False) a typo on the "forme.save" for form.save right?

Comment: @ClydeMulenga yes you are right sorry for the typo ).i have edited my answer

Comment: @ClydeMulenga did it answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks alot @amadou sow let me try it i'll inform you shortly.